# Using @FindBy is displaying an nullpointerexception error message using Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy trabajando con Selenium y jva y estaba haciendo unos test en una web demo y estaba funcionando bien peor ahora esta mostrando un nullpointerexception error, pense que podia ser por usar el @FindBy pero no es eso porque falla si uso tambien el WebElement creo que es algo de la clase donde hago el metodo clickLogo, intente con otras respuestas aqui pero nada funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El constructor

```
    public class PageObject {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    public PageObject(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
        
    }
```

Esta es la pagina donde busco los elementos

```
public class Home_Page extends PageObject {

    public Home_Page(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        
    }

    @FindBy(id = "nava")
    public static WebElement logo;

   
}
```

Donde se hacen los steps

```
public class Home_Page_Steps {
   
    public WebDriver driver;

   public void clickLogo(){
    Home_Page.logo.click();
     //driver.findElement(By.id("nava"));
   }

   
   
}
```

y donde mando llamar los metodos

```
public class home_Page {

    public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Home_Page_Steps hps = new Home_Page_Steps();
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public static void main(String[] args){
       //driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        System.setProperty("wedriver.chrome.driver", Utils.PathDriver);
    }

    @Test()
    public void openWebPage(){
        driver.get(Utils.BASE_URL);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
    }

    @Test(testName = "Click Logo")
    public void clickLogo(){
        openWebPage();
        hps.clickLogo();
        //WebElement logo = driver.findElement(By.id("nava"));
        //logo.click();
        //hps.clickLogo();
    }

    
    

}
```

Comment: Hi there Mr. Luis Uribe (nice english name). Have you noticed something weird? The UI of this site is shown in Spanish, so, my question is: why did you asked in another language?. Supongo que te has confundido por un momento. Pero esto es [es.so], por lo tanto las preguntas y respuestas han de estar escritas en castellano. Si deseas publicar en inglés, debes usar [so]. Ahora, antes que pienses que te estoy troleando, te invito a realizar el [tour], donde se expone la motivación del uso del castellano aquí. Haz clic en [edit] y traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: @ElTroll jajaj perdon tienes razon no me di cuenta en que plaforma estaba y nomas empece a escrbir